# export corrplot to .eps file

Tags: r, eps, r-corrplot

I have a plotted a `corrplot` and I want to have it in .eps file format. The problem is that in the .eps file, the numbers inside the circles are vanished. Is there any parameter to get them back?

```
library(corrplot)
test <- structure(c(100, 41.6411042944785, 69.6478873239437, 99.35956084172, 
 100, 99.9295774647887, 90.4849039341263, 54.409509202454, 100
 ), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("x1", "x2", "x3"), c("x1", 
 "x2", "x3")))
```

without .eps format: (perform well)

```
corrplot(round(test),tl.cex=1.5,title="test", method="circle",is.corr=FALSE,type="full",
    cl.lim=c(0,100),cl.cex=2,addgrid.col="blue",addshade="positive",col=col1, addCoef.col = rgb(0,0,0, alpha =0.6), mar=c(0,0,1,0), diag= FALSE)
```

In .eps format:

```
postscript("test.eps", height=8, width=8, paper="special", family="Helvetica", fonts="Helvetica", horizontal=FALSE, onefile=FALSE)
corrplot(round(test),tl.cex=1.5,title="test", method="circle",is.corr=FALSE,type="full",
         cl.lim=c(0,100),cl.cex=2,addgrid.col="blue",addshade="positive",col=col1, addCoef.col = rgb(0,0,0, alpha =0.6), mar=c(0,0,1,0), diag= FALSE)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the warning that said

> Warning message:
>   In text.default(Pos[, 1], Pos[, 2], col = addCoef.col, labels = round((DAT -  :
>     semi-transparency is not supported on this device: reported only once per page

?  That means that any colours you try to draw with semi-transparency (hint, hint: the `alpha` settings in your `addCoef.col` argument) won't work in a PostScript plot.

Eliminating the `alpha` setting as follows (just changing the colour from `rgb(0,0,0,alpha=0.6)` to `rgb(0,0,0)`, although you might as well say `"black"`) works fine on my system:

```
library("corrplot")
col1 <- "green"  ## you didn't tell us what col1 was so I made something up
postscript("test.eps", height=8, width=8, paper="special",
    family="Helvetica", fonts="Helvetica", horizontal=FALSE, onefile=FALSE)
corrplot(round(test),tl.cex=1.5,title="test", method="circle",
    is.corr=FALSE,type="full",
    cl.lim=c(0,100),cl.cex=2,
    addgrid.col="blue",addshade="positive",
    col=col1, addCoef.col = rgb(0,0,0), mar=c(0,0,1,0), diag= FALSE)
dev.off()
```